# What's the equivalent of Android's Loader in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know which Xamarin.Forms's component corresponds to Android's Loader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XF is primarily a UI framework.  Loader is not really a UI widget.  You can access the native Android loader in your Forms app by using DependencyService, but you might be better off using C# TPL or async/await to do background tasks.